# Encoding properties for each point in a GeoJSON multipoint

Tags: geojson, standards

I'm working with GeoJSON Multipoints and wondering if there's any way of encoding properties for each point in the array? I realise this is a vague question but I'm looking for suggestions as to how I might achieve this or if there's a standard I'm unaware of.

**AN EXAMPLE**

In the example below I would be looking for a way for `point1_property` to represent a value for the first point in the MultiPoint array and `point2_property` to represent a value for the second point.

```
{  
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "geometry":
                {
                    "type": "MultiPoint",
                    "coordinates": [ 
                        [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0] 
                    ]
                },
                "properties":{  
                "point1_property":"value1",
                "point2_property":"value2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You must explode multipoint geometry into elementary geometries and attach attributes from the right columns to those. Is there a fixed number of members (points) in your MultiPoints or can it vary?

Comment: No the number of points can vary wildly. Could you give an example of what this might look like. I'm currently in the process of writing a serializer. Thanks!

Comment: You could convert your data into PostGIS, use ST_DumpPoints http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html and continue from that somehow. Alternative route could be to use SpatiaLite and ElementaryGeometries https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. However, I believe you would like to do it with a script or a program but I can't show any examples about that. For my mind the main problem is in the data. It should not contain MultiPoints if each point has its own attributes but data should consist of many simple points instead.

Answer (score 13):

In GeoJSON, features and feature collections have properties, Geometries don't.

Points in a Multipoint geometry all inherit the same properties of their container feature.

The standard way to express this in GeoJson would be a Feature Collection containing a collection of features, each feature contains a point geometry and arbitrary properties.

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
        "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
      },
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.0, 1.5]},
        "properties": {"prop0": "value1"}
      }
   ]
}
```

This might not be convenient or efficient in your case. There is no standard way to do this in GeoJson. Your proposed array of properties not invalid but application dependent. [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) is correct

> "the main problem is in the data. It should not contain MultiPoints if each point has its own attributes"

Answer (score -1):

You can use "coordinates" with length 3 (see [geojson spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-9)) for numeric parameter like the depth for each point. If your data has parameter for each point or can be represented by array with length equal to multipoint coordinates array, I suggest you use the properties as a list, this would be more efficient:

```
{  
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {
            "type":"Feature",
            "geometry":
                {
                    "type": "MultiPoint",
                    "coordinates": [ 
                        [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0] 
                    ]
                },
                "properties":{  
                "prop0":["value1", "value2"],
                "prop1":[0.1, 0.2]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```