# How can I add dynamic text/properties to a GeoJSON multipoint on each individual feature?

Tags: geojson, style

I'm drawing circles on a map based on lon/lat. These circles are drawn from "subarrays" in an array, e.g:

```
myArray = [[array(18)]],[array(111)], [array(65)]....]
```

I map each of these arrays using GeoJSON like this:

```
var geojsonlatObject = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'crs': {
                'type': 'name',
                'properties': {
                'name': 'EPSG:4326'
            }
        },
        'features':
            [{
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'MultiPoint',
                    'coordinates': circlecoordinates().map(function (x) {
                        //console.log(x[0][0]);
                        //console.log(x[0][1]);
                        return ol.proj.transform([x[0][0], x[0][1]], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
                    })
                }
            }]
    };
```

Further, I have a style like this:

```
    var locationandtransitstyle = new ol.style.Style({
        
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: String(resultArray.length),//this.length,//'15',
            scale: 1.7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffffff'
            })
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 15,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(30,144,255,0.7)'
        })             
      })
    })
```

The result of this is that I have the length of myArray in each circle. But I want the length of the subarrays as text inside the circles. Any ideas on how to do this?

My thoughts at the moment is that I can add use the "properties" option in GeoJSON, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946, but I don't know how to implement it for each feature...

```
    ......."coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "***for-circle add array lenght***"
  }
```

**UPDATE**

After some more experimenting i came to the following:
I can log length of the subarrays by:

```
console.log(x.length);
```

inside my map function. Can i use that to set this value to a properti??:

```
'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'MultiPoint',
                    'coordinates': circlecoordinates().map(function (x) {
                        console.log(x[0][0]);
                        console.log(x[0][1]);
                        console.log(x.length);
                        return ol.proj.transform([x[0][0], x[0][1]], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
                    })
                },
                "properties": {
                    "name": "...value of x.length..."
                }
            }]
```

Is it possible to do this, or will it not work? Do i need a .map()-function in for the property as well?

**Alternatively**:

```
properties": {
                    "name": circlecoordinates().map(function (x) {
                         return    x.length
                            }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

As for now i think the answer to my question is here: 
[Encoding properties for each point in a GeoJSON multipoint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184708/encoding-properties-for-each-point-in-a-geojson-multipoint)

So, i will abandon current path, and try to restructure my data.