# How to get individual features from a GeoJson-Multipoint feature using map.on('click'…) in openlayers 4.6.5

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, features

I'm trying to get the features of each MultiPoint-point when i click on a point in my openlayers map (4.6.5). The points shows on the map.

I want to add a pop-up on each feature when i click on the points in my MultiPoint array. Each individual point consists of [LON, LAT, TIME].

In have previously achieved this with a "LineString" geometry. So i wonder if this a problem with "MULTIPOINT" as geometry?

My click function looks like this:

```
 map.on('click', function (evt) {
    var pointfeature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, vectorLayer) {

        if (feature) {
console.log(feature)
           var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
            var hdms = 
ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 
'EPSG:4326'));

        var geometry = feature.getGeometry(); 
        var mypoint = geometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);
        var pointtoshow = point[1];
        content.innerHTML = '<p>feature </p>';
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        }
        return feature;
    });
});
```

My geojsonObject looks like this:

```
var geojsonObject = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'crs': {
        'type': 'name',
        'properties': {
            'name': 'EPSG:3857'
        }
    },
    'features':[
'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'MultiPoint',
                'coordinates': 
                    mycoordinates().map(function (x) {

                        return ol.proj.transform([x[0], x[1]], 
   'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
                    })
                ,
                "properties": {
                    "Time": mycoordinates().map(function (x)         
                {
                        return x[2]
                })
            }
        },{
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point', 
            'coordinates': ol.proj.transform([refpointlon, refpointlat], 
        'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') 
        }]
};
```

What i get from the console.log(feature) is the following:

```
Hk {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 2, …}
N: {geometry: No}
Wa: {}
a: "geometry"
ab: {change:geometry: Array(1), change: Array(1), propertychange:         
Array(1)}
c: undefined
f: null
g: 1
i:
Ch: Hk {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 2, …}
Dh: ƒ b(b)
Eh: false
listener: ƒ ()
target: No {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 1, …}
type: "change"
__proto__: Object
j: undefined
oa: {change:geometry: Array(1), change: Array(1), propertychange:         
Array(1)}
qa: {}
xp: 2
__proto__: Vc
```

But this does not contain the feature coordinates, and not the feature property: TIME, as spesified in the geojsonobject.

Any suggestions for why i don't get the individual feature-information??

Comment: If i choose another feature, it gives me: Hk {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 4, …}
N:
geometry: C {    .......... Which is C for Circle i think. Then if i choose my MultiPoint-feature I get the follwoing:  Hk {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 2, …}
N:
geometry: No {Wa:      ...........What means "No", is it trying to tell me that it is NOT a geometry?

Comment: You can grab the geometry using `feature.getGeometry()` (which you did there, so I don't know where is the problem actually). And the property can be grabbed with `feature.get('time')`.

Comment: If i do feature.getGeometry(), i get this: No {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 1, …}          However, it does not contain the properties I so badly need. If i do feature.get('time'), i only get "undefined"

Comment: And what about feature.get('Time'). I missed the capital 'T' before.

Comment: I corrected for that, does not help. :)

Comment: Okay, and what is the output from mycoordinates() ? This is really weird way to build geojson object, maybe it is incorrect there.

Comment: function mycoordinates() { return allpositions;
    }                    First i create a array "allposition" with [Lon[i], Lat[i], Time[i]], then i call this function to map the geojson object, i know that works because if i log the geoJson object, it will show the correct structure of a geoJson object.... It is also referenced as a Multipoint.

Comment: I will structure my geoJson object in a different way, you might be right. I will revert with progress. Thanks'

Comment: I belive the answer is here, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184708/encoding-properties-for-each-point-in-a-geojson-multipoint MultiPoint does not go hand-in-hand with individual parameters for each point ( It seems).

Comment: It's not in the GeoJson standard but it can be done in OpenLayers because it also supports Z and M coordinate layouts used for GPX https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.geom.html#.GeometryLayout

Answer (score 1):

Leave the time value in the coordinates, just as you would for GPX:

```
var geojsonObject = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'crs': {
        'type': 'name',
        'properties': {
            'name': 'EPSG:3857'
        }
    },
    'features':[
'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'MultiPoint',
                'coordinates': 
                    mycoordinates().map(function (x) {
                        // include time in coordinates
                        return ol.proj.transform(x, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
                    })
                ,
                "properties": {
                    "Time": mycoordinates().map(function (x)         
                {
                        return x[2]
                })
            }
        },{
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point', 
            'coordinates': ol.proj.transform([refpointlon, refpointlat], 
        'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') 
        }]
};
```

Then you can get the time from the result of `getClosestPoint()`:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
    var pointfeature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, vectorLayer) {

        if (feature) {
console.log(feature)
           var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
            var hdms = 
ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 
'EPSG:4326'));

        var geometry = feature.getGeometry(); 
        var mypoint = geometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);
        var time = mypoint[2];
        content.innerHTML = '<p>feature </p>';
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        }
        return feature;
    });
});
```

Here's a simple example using coordinates from a GPX linestring as a multipoint and displaying time when the mouse moves over a point https://jsfiddle.net/tbod7g05/

As OpenLayers only supports two extra coordinate properties (intended for altitude and time) if you needed more you could use the "altitude" to pass an index to your other properties:

```
var geojsonObject = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'crs': {
        'type': 'name',
        'properties': {
            'name': 'EPSG:3857'
        }
    },
    'features':[
'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'MultiPoint',
                'coordinates': 
                    mycoordinates().map(function (x, index) {
                       return ol.proj.transform([x[0], x[1], index], 
   'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
                     })
                ,
                "properties": {
                    "Time": mycoordinates().map(function (x)         
                {
                        return x[2]
                })
            }
        },{
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point', 
            'coordinates': ol.proj.transform([refpointlon, refpointlat], 
        'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') 
        }]
};


map.on('click', function (evt) {
    var pointfeature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, vectorLayer) {

        if (feature) {
console.log(feature)
           var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
            var hdms = 
ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 
'EPSG:4326'));

        var geometry = feature.getGeometry(); 
        var mypoint = geometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);
        var index = mypoint[2];
        var time = feature.get('Time')[index];
        content.innerHTML = '<p>feature </p>';
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        }
        return feature;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, tnx for the suggestion. What if i have more properties then just the 'time'?

Comment: As long as your time and other property arrays are in the same order as the points so you could pass the index value in the coordinates.  I've added that to the code.